# No installation candidate for compiz

Tags: apt, compiz

I tried to install 3d effect on my Debian Wheezy using command

```
$ apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-gnome compiz-gtk
```

But it gives the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package compiz is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'compiz' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package compizconfig-settings-manager
E: Unable to locate package compiz-fusion-plugins-main
E: Unable to locate package compiz-gnome
E: Unable to locate package compiz-gtk
```

What should I do now?

Comment: You can probably install it on wheezy from squeeze if you really want to. At the worst you should be able to recompile the sources on wheezy.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks. Could you please show me how? Reply as an answer if you wish.

Comment: I don't know how well compiz can work with gnome3 since gnome3 itself comes with a compositing window manager. Also, compiz development [has stopped](https://answers.launchpad.net/compiz/+question/235670) which is probably why it's been removed from the Debian repos. However, a lot of compiz's functionality is natively available in gnome3. Anything in particular you were looking for?

Comment: @zhangwfjh After somewhat extraordinary efforts, I managed to build compiz on wheezy. However, I then made the mistake of running it. It trashed my desktop to the extent KDE stopped responding normally and I could not focus on any window to write anything. Fortunately, I was still able to get to a terminal and so was able to reboot. The upshot is that I can write down a sketch of what is involved, but you will probably have difficulty in building it yourself. Also, it will probably not work correctly, though maybe it will work Ok on Gnome, I dunno.

Comment: If you are using amd64 I could also upload my binaries somewhere so you could get them.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Wow, thank you very very much and sorry for troubling you. I would give it up, or at least set it aside for a while because I just got a more serious problem on my Debian. After updating using update manager, words and icons for GNOME environment all become small blocks. I feel a bad first impression for Debian now.

Comment: @zhangwfjh Don't judge Debian too harshly. Bugs will creep in, and in general Debian is very good and very quality-conscious. You can report your problem to the bug tracker and also ask in Debian forums - mailing lists and IRC for example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I know that. I'm a very beginner for Linux so I don't know much about how to solve problems by myself. Do I need to first learn something? Any suggestions?

Comment: @zhangwfjh: Just keep learning. If you have questions you can ask here. You could also hang out in the chat room of unix.sx and talk to people, though in general "serious" questions should be asked on the main site. I think you need more rep, maybe 50? There are other forums like IRC that you could hang out in. There are some good books available free, like the [Debian Handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/).

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thank you. I'll see. What do you think if I begin from Ubuntu, which I heard is easier for beginner?

Comment: @zhangwfjh I suggest you try different things and see what you like. Ubuntu is basically Debian with a few different features and a bit of user-level polishing. However, Debian stable is significantly less buggy than most versions of Ubuntu, though not usually as up to date. Whether it will suit you better than Debian or vice versa is hard to say. These days there are a lot of choices out there.

Answer (score 3):

(Google debian compiz.)

Debian Package Tracking System :: http://packages.qa.debian.org/c/compiz.html

It was removed post squeeze as "buggy, and unmaintained".

Comment: Well, so I have to wait to update?

Comment: Beyond debian 6, it does not exist. Unless someone steps up to be the debian maintainer, it will not be re-added to the pool.

Answer (score -1):

Try,`sudo apt-get update`

then retry the installation.

I had the same problem and it worked for me.